# Directly referencing a static nested class in java

Tags: java, static-methods, inner-classes, static-classes

[Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) says:

> Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name

Yet, I'm able to access and reference the static nested class WITHOUT specifying the enclosing class name:

**Test.java** (in some other package)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //referencing the static class without the enclosing class name!
   Builder b = new Builder(); //ok! no need for "Response.Builder"
}

// also from a non-static method
public void foo() {
   //referencing the static class without the enclosing class name!
   Builder b = new Builder(); //ok! no need for "Response.Builder"
}
```

What am I missing here? Does not this contradict the spec?

**Response.java** (the enclosing class) and **Builder.java** (the static nested class):

```
public class Response {

    public static class Builder {


    public Builder() {

    }


    public Response build() {
       // build Response instance
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Maybe you have `import` at the top.

Comment: Please post a complete example.

Comment: you have static import....

Comment: I do have a regular import: 
import com.mycompnay.Response.Builder;
is this the reason?

Comment: Your link is to a tutorial, not to the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your comments: Static imports are used to reference static methods and fields directly. For types, regular imports are the way to go, also for static nested types.

Remove the import statement and your code will break.